# Elasticsearch not sync from first time update[Express, mongoosastic]

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I have problem with mongoosastic it not update Elasticsearch from first update. I update 1 time and nothing happend and then update 2 time and in elasticsearch make update from what I updated 1st time...

Here is my code:

```
var User = system.mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');

User.createMapping(function (err, mapping) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error creating mapping");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Mapping created");
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});

//{$in: ['doctor','nurse']}
var stream = User.synchronize();
var count = 0;

stream.on('data', function (data) {
    count++;
});

stream.on('close', function () {
    console.log("Indexed " + count + " documents");
});

stream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Anyone know what is problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what you expected, and what you got.

But I am going to guess that you are experiencing a race condition because you started `User.synchronize()` before `User.createMapping()` finished.

If so, this might work better:

```
var User = system.mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');

User.createMapping(function (err, mapping) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error creating mapping");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Mapping created");
        console.log(mapping);

        doTheNextThing();
    }
});

function doTheNextThing () {
    //{$in: ['doctor','nurse']}
    var stream = User.synchronize();
    var count = 0;

    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        count++;
    });

    stream.on('close', function () {
        console.log("Indexed " + count + " documents");
    });

    stream.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```